# Validation with CrudRepository

Tags: appscan

I'm using HCL cloud.appscan.com and I have Validation.Required warnings on things like this:

Source: com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper.readValue(String;Class):Object via myclass...

Sink:       org.springframework.data.repository.CrudRepository.save(Object):Object via myclass...

In my code I do validate it, but I have no idea how it determines if I am validating the objects before persisting.  What code do I need to clear the warnings?

```
try {

        Validate.isTrue(myObject.getMyInt() >= 0);
        
        record.setMyObject(myObject.getMyInt());
        
        save(record);

} catch (Exception e){
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mark this warning as noise since you are already validating the input. If you really don't want to report this finding during the scan, you can create a validation method and add a [@ValidatorMethod](https://help.hcltechsw.com/appscan/ASoC/src_java_annotations.html#src_java_annotations__validator_method) (Java) or [[ValidatorMethod]](https://help.hcltechsw.com/appscan/ASoC/src_dotnet_annotations.html#src_dotnet_annotations__validator_method) (C#) using AppScan annotation library.

For Example

```
...
isValid(myObject);
record.setMyObject(myObject.getMyInt());
save(record);
...

@ValidationMethod
isValid(YourObject myObject) {
   Validate.isTrue(myObject.getMyInt() >= 0);
}
```